# htaccess or php 301 redirect url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I do not know a lot htaccess and redirect url (301) with php as;

```
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: http://www.exampledomain.com" );
```

Is there any difference or advantage between the two for google?Can I must use htaccess for redirect url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use both these headers to redirect something permanently. Both headers are needed. I echo this same header for my old blog url. And I get all the referrals, visitors, inlinks from google to the new domain.

**It does not matter how you echo the headers. It matters those headers exist.**

I know PHP well so I have used a PHP file that echos only these headers

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://shiplu.mokadd.im/
```

If you use `302` redirect Google will remember your current url and associate all your links to that old url.